# Is there a one to one mapping in channelOpen and channelClosed upstream events in Netty 3?

Tags: java, netty, channel

According to the doc https://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelEvent.html there are 2 upstream events that change the state of OPEN channel:

> channelOpen (state = OPEN, value = true)
>
> channelClosed (state = OPEN, value = false)

and one downstream event:

> close (state = OPEN, value = false)

However I cannot find any documentation regarding whether there's a guaranteed one to one relationship between upstream channelOpen and channelClosed events. I.e. is it guaranteed that if channelOpen event is fired then a channelClosed event will be fired as well and exactly once, regardless which party (client or server) and how (gracefully or ungracefully) closes the socket?

What I want to implement is a mechanism to limit number of open channels in my application. To achieve that I intend to have a shared instance of SimpleChannelHandler added to every channel pipeline and increment/decrement the counter in:

channelClosed and channelOpen methods:

https://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelHandler.html#channelOpen(org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent)
https://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelHandler.html#channelClosed(org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent)

Is it a correct way to implement such mechanism? Or there might be cases where upstream channelClosed events is not generated and one should inspect the downstream events as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of netty 3.x is end of life forever so you should upgrade to 4.1.x. That said yes there once you receive an `open` you will also receive a `close`.